# Pairing of bluetooth device fails although PIN should be ok

Tags: bluetooth, kubuntu, bluez

I am attempting to pair a DataLogic QBT2400 Scanner to a Linux Host system (a Kubuntu 22.04 box). The scanner should support the bluetooth serial port profile.

I do see the scanner, but pairing always fails. I restored the scanner to factory defaults, where the PIN should be 1234, but this does not work. I then set the PIN of the scanner to another value, as described in the manual (by scanning QR codes), but this also failed.

I therefore think that something else is going wrong, but don't know how to further debug this.

Here is the session I get:

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller E8:48:B8:C8:20:00 Pairable: yes
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller E8:48:B8:C8:20:00 Discovering: yes
[CHG] Device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F LegacyPairing: yes
[CHG] Device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F RSSI: -56
[CHG] Device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F RSSI: -72
[CHG] Device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F RSSI: -60
[CHG] Device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F RSSI: -76
[CHG] Device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F RSSI: -66
[bluetooth]# devices
Device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F QuickScan-QBT2400 E22N55637
[bluetooth]# scan off
Discovery stopped
[CHG] Device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F RSSI is nil
[CHG] Controller E8:48:B8:C8:20:00 Discovering: no
[bluetooth]# trust 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F 
[CHG] Device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F Trusted: yes
Changing 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# pair 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F 
Attempting to pair with 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F
[CHG] Device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F Connected: yes
Request PIN code
[agent] Enter PIN code: 1234
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationRejected
[CHG] Device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F Connected: no
```

I enabled debugging for the bluetooth service, but did not spot anything informative (to me) there.

```
Jul 14 16:10:59 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_complete() status 0x00
Jul 14 16:10:59 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:discovering_callback() hci0 type 7 discovering 1 method 0
Jul 14 16:11:03 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:device_found_callback() hci0 addr 71:A6:FF:4E:25:D3, rssi -72 flags 0x0004 eir_len 35
Jul 14 16:11:09 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:discovering_callback() hci0 type 7 discovering 0 method 0
Jul 14 16:11:09 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:trigger_start_discovery()
Jul 14 16:11:09 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:cancel_passive_scanning()
Jul 14 16:11:15 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_timeout()
Jul 14 16:11:15 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_timeout() adapter->current_discovery_filter == 0
Jul 14 16:11:15 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_complete() status 0x00
Jul 14 16:11:15 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:discovering_callback() hci0 type 7 discovering 1 method 0
Jul 14 16:11:16 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:stop_discovery() sender :1.105
Jul 14 16:11:16 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:stop_discovery_complete() status 0x00
Jul 14 16:11:16 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:discovery_remove() owner :1.105
Jul 14 16:11:16 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:discovery_free() 0x560752ccd150
Jul 14 16:11:16 bluetoothd[2830]: src/device.c:device_set_rssi_with_delta() rssi 0
Jul 14 16:11:16 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:trigger_passive_scanning()
Jul 14 16:11:16 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:discovering_callback() hci0 type 7 discovering 0 method 0
Jul 14 16:11:26 bluetoothd[2830]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x560752cc3c00: ref=2
Jul 14 16:11:26 bluetoothd[2830]: src/device.c:bonding_request_new() Requesting bonding for 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F
Jul 14 16:11:26 bluetoothd[2830]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x560752cc3c00: ref=3
Jul 14 16:11:26 bluetoothd[2830]: src/agent.c:agent_unref() 0x560752cc3c00: ref=2
Jul 14 16:11:26 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:suspend_discovery()
Jul 14 16:11:26 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:adapter_bonding_attempt() hci0 bdaddr 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F type 0 io_cap 0x04
Jul 14 16:11:27 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F connected eir_len 29
Jul 14 16:11:27 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:pin_code_request_callback() hci0 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F
Jul 14 16:11:27 bluetoothd[2830]: plugins/autopair.c:autopair_pincb() device 'QuickScan-QBT2400 E22N55' (00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F) class: 0x180000 vid/pid: 0x0/0x0
Jul 14 16:11:27 bluetoothd[2830]: src/device.c:new_auth() Requesting agent authentication for 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F
Jul 14 16:11:27 bluetoothd[2830]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x560752cc3c00: ref=3
Jul 14 16:11:29 bluetoothd[2830]: src/agent.c:agent_ref() 0x560752cc3c00: ref=4
Jul 14 16:11:29 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:btd_adapter_pincode_reply() hci0 addr 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F pinlen 4
Jul 14 16:11:29 bluetoothd[2830]: src/agent.c:agent_unref() 0x560752cc3c00: ref=3
Jul 14 16:11:29 bluetoothd[2830]: src/agent.c:agent_unref() 0x560752cc3c00: ref=2
Jul 14 16:11:30 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:pair_device_complete() Rejected (0x0b)
Jul 14 16:11:30 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F type 0 status 0xb
Jul 14 16:11:30 bluetoothd[2830]: src/device.c:device_bonding_complete() bonding 0x560752ccb710 status 0x0b
Jul 14 16:11:30 bluetoothd[2830]: src/device.c:device_cancel_authentication() Canceling authentication request for 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F
Jul 14 16:11:30 bluetoothd[2830]: src/device.c:device_bonding_failed() status 11
Jul 14 16:11:30 bluetoothd[2830]: src/agent.c:agent_unref() 0x560752cc3c00: ref=1
Jul 14 16:11:30 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()
Jul 14 16:11:32 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F disconnected, reason 2
Jul 14 16:11:32 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection()
Jul 14 16:11:32 bluetoothd[2830]: plugins/policy.c:disconnect_cb() reason 2
Jul 14 16:11:32 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 00:07:BE:3E:9C:5F type 0 status 0xe
Jul 14 16:11:32 bluetoothd[2830]: src/device.c:device_bonding_complete() bonding (nil) status 0x0e
Jul 14 16:11:32 bluetoothd[2830]: src/device.c:device_bonding_failed() status 14
Jul 14 16:11:32 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()
Jul 14 16:11:48 bluetoothd[2830]: src/adapter.c:stop_discovery() sender :1.105
```

Any idea what I could try next?